# How to check if backend is healthy in vcl_recv

Tags: proxy, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have pretty sophisticated varnish config. I can't really use the directors and doing the routes manually.

```
//webservice1 and webservice2 has probes working there

set req.backend = webservice1;
if (req.backend.healthy)
{ 
     #redirect there 
}

set req.backend = webservice2;
if(req.backend.healthy)
{ 
     #change parameters with regex and redirect
}
```

This works. But looks really lame.

Is there any "legal" way to find out if backend is healthy? Like this:

```
if(webservice2.healthy)
{ 
     #change parameters with regex and redirect
}
```

This is not working, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been doing a lot of research about this and that's the only way to accomplish it (unless you want to write a vmod).

Assuming you always want to respond with webservice1 unless it's sick, I may suggest a little refactoring:

```
set req.backend = webservice1;
if(!req.backend.healthy) {
     set req.backend = webservice2;
     #change parameters with regex
}
# redirect here
```

Comment: If you not sure/have suggestion you should write it as comment not as answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I can't make comments due to my low reputation.
In addition, isn't an answer that there are no answers for that question? :)

Comment: I have the same problem, and this is not working in Varnish 4

Comment: So you downvoted me just because it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Geez, I've been using your answer for 3 years as one of my most important data about varnish, but never acked this as a solution. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of search with google, i found this [link](https://www.varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2014-May/023693.html), where they are speaking about migration to V4.

the code :

```
if(!req.backend.healthy) {
  #your logic
}
```

is valid for Varnish 3 and not for varnish 4.

**For varnish 4:**

Take a look here:
https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/users-guide/vcl-grace.html#users-guide-handling-misbehaving-servers

So the solution will be:

```
import std;
set req.backend_hint = webservice1;
if (!std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
    set req.backend_hint = webservice2;
}
```

I hope this help you :)

Comment: He didn't ask for a Varnish 4 solution, but is good to have both versions.

Comment: Funny part is that 3 years later I was upgrading from varnish 3 to 4 and I ran into the same problem. I googled around and run into your answer. Good so far. I decided to upvote it, and once I logged in I figured that I'm looking at my old question.